# Test class coverage for dynamic SOQL

Tags: apex, controller, visualforce-component, custom

Can any one please help me to cover below method containing dynamic SOQL

```
public PageReference query() {
        message = 'SELECT ';
        Boolean first = true;
        for ( SelectOption so : selectedFields ) {
            if (!first) {
                message += ', ';
            }
            message +=  so.getValue() + '';
            //message += so.getLabel() + ' (' + so.getValue() + ')';
            first = false;
        }
        message = message + ' FROM' + ' ' + selectedObject;
        return null;       
    }
```

Comment: you need to define values for `selectedFields`, `selectedObject` and then call this method at your test class

Comment: Some advice for the future: -- You'll probably find that your question will get a better response if you include the code (in this case, both the code you're trying to test, and the test class/methods) that you already have. -- Code coverage questions are a pretty common topic here, and the answers generally all follow the same theme. Try searching for some (they might help you). -- Coverage is gained when a line of code is executed as a result of running a test method. Your test is responsible for making code run, so if lines aren't covered, you probably need to create additional test data.

Answer (score 1):

In your test class, define values for given variables as below in your test class. Replace YourClassName with your apex class name:

```
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('Name','Name'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Company','Company'));
YourClassName.selectedFields  = options;
YourClassName.selectedObject= 'Account';
YourClassName.query();
```

Comment: Done! How to cover MetaData Part ? 
Below is the code,public void showChildFields() {mandateFieldList = new list<string>();
list<All_Object__mdt> objectMetadataType = [select id , developername,Exceptions__c from All_Object__mdt where developername =: selectedObject];

Comment: list<string> exceptionalFieldsList = new list<string>(); if(objectMetadataType != null && objectMetadataType.size()>0){string objectexceptionalField = objectMetadataType[0].Exceptions__c; if(objectexceptionalField != null && objectexceptionalField.contains(',')){exceptionalFieldsList = objectexceptionalField.split(','); exceptionalFieldsSet.addAll(exceptionalFieldsList); }else{exceptionalFieldsSet.add(objectexceptionalField);

Comment: AyubAnsari Please don't beg for upvotes or answer acceptance. That said... @user46824 if an answer helped you solve your issue, please consider upvoting it (once you have enough reputation) and accepting it. These actions are voluntary, but help let other people with similar issues see which answers are helpful.

Comment: @user46824 Putting code into comments doesn't work very well because of the limited number of characters and the limited formatting options. Beyond that, it sounds like you have a similar, but separate question. You should consider creating another question for it. However, before you do, take some time to try for yourself to gain coverage. This question required you to create some `selectOption` instances so you actually had something for your `for` loop to work on. Your new question likely has a similar answer. Try to apply what you learned here.